# Mismatched managed dependencies in a spring boot app resulting in a classpath version issue

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

I have a spring boot app, version 2.1.7, which brings in spring-boot-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE. The maven build is all good. However when I try to start the spring boot app it complains by saying:

```java
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration
```

My dependency tree looks like this:

```xml
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:test
```

Comment: when I get to the line of code where the error is originating, it is taking me to a spring-webmvc jar of version 5.2.3.RELEASE instead of 5.1.9.RELEASE.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Best would be having a full pom file or even better a link to a github project?

Comment: I had to switch to a completely diff approach and so couldn't get pom.xml to share. Thanks for your responses.